# Magento Apply percent discount only on one matching items

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

Can anyone help me find the products in current shopping cart matching the applied coupon criteria?

Actually I need to set the custom discount (50% on highest one) amount on any one matching products, By default Magento applied the 50% discount in all the matching products buy I need to apply discount on only one item.

I have make some Google and get some links on [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546410/magento-how-do-i-find-out-if-a-sales-rule-coupon-exists-for-a-product-item) and [http://www.magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/201516/#t303924), but not able to get any solution or suggestion.

**e.g.** I have four items in the cart in those two items matching the coupon criteria (Whatever we have set in condition), So by default Magento apply 50% discount (set in coupon) on these two items, but I want to give the discount only on one(highest price) out of these 2.

"Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" is work only for same item not for multiple items

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the item filter of the rule (Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions ). Unfortunately, the list of operators is limited and adding aggregate functions (MAX, MIN) would be a non-trivial task.

Anyway, what you're after is just one of a few neat features of this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/special-promotions-pro-5784.html

Comment: Thanks @Jan Tomka for your reply but this extension not suitable for me, Can you tell me how to get the all items in current cart matching any coupon criteria ?